# How to copy file from SecureCRT Linux server to Windows desktop using command or shell script?

Tags: linux, windows, scp

Please don't suggest tools like WinSCP, PuTTY, etc., as I have already tried the following `scp` commands on the Linux server, but am still not getting the output:

```
scp /file/to/send username@remote:/where/to/put
scp username@remote:/file/to/send /where/to/put
scp username@source:/location/to/file username@destination:/where/to/put
```

I am not much aware about the commands, so please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: What errors are your receiving when using `scp`?  There's simply not enough information in your question to provide any help or guidance... helpful info such as what you've tried, if other than `scp`, **and** errors received.

Answer (score 1):

It´s easy, but maybe you are a bit confused. First, this is what you want?
Linux server --> Win PC

The errors:
SecureCRT is not a server, is a software (the best) for remote access. Also, when you type your showed command sentences on the Linux server, you are trying to connect from his ssh client software (in the Linux server) to a ssh server (the Win PC) -> probably you have not installed a ssh server in the Win PC so it is a conceptual mistake.

SCP is a protocol that goes over SSH, so you need to install a SSH server in one machine and a SSH client in the other side. You will always need a client and a server SSH pair. You can choose 1 device as a SSH server but the other must be the SSH client. The SSH server is a service that is waiting for requests from SSH clients, because SSH is a protocol that works on a client-server basis. When you type SCP transfer commands you are using the SSH client software that is installed in this machine (could be a desktop PC or a server of other services, but always is acting as  client for SSH) and the remote machine (the other side) is acting as a server for SSH. In the machine that you choose to act as a server, you install the server software and in the client machine, you install the client software, but you can install both types of software in the same machine. Normally you install SSH server software in the Linux server to give him the remote access from other machine (the PC ssh client) and also you install the SSH client software in the Linux server to give him the option to connect to other machines (acting as ssh servers). In the PC normally you install only the ssh client software, but you can also install the ssh server software if you want.

The Linux server could be the SSH server or the SSH client -> you choose his role.  Here the commands for just one option, the Linux server as a SSH server.

***1) Linux server as SSH server*** (is the best option because openssh is already installed on the linux servers)=> in this case the Win PC must be the SSH client.
You need to install a SSH server software on the Linux and a SSH client software on the Win PC. For ex., you can install openssh server and opensshclient (yes, is also available for win, for free).

***Linux server (SSH server)** (if is not already installed)*

Debian,Ubuntu          -> `# apt install openssh-server`

RedHat, Centos, fedora -> `# yum install openssh-server`

Check the ssh server status:

> `# systemctl status sshd`

or `# service sshd status` or other linux command

If is no started:

> `# systemctl start sshd`

***WinPC (SSH client):***

*Requirements:*

> - Win 10 1809 or superior version.
> - Powershell (is already installed and enabled) as ADMINISTRATOR
> - OpenSSH client is already installed. you just need to enable it.

from and ADMIN cmd or shell (command prompt -> right click -> Run As Admnistrator):

```
 C:\> powershell
 Windows PowerShell  Copyright (C) Microsoft
 Corporation. All rights reserved.  Try the new cross-platform
 PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
 
 PS C:\>
 PS C:\> Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed                --> the OpenSSHclient is installed and enabled

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent               --> the OpenSSHserver is disabled
```

***In this case you have the openssh client OK!!
But only if your openssh Client is "NotPresent" you should do this step:***

```
PS C:\> Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0

Path :
Online : True
RestartNeeded : False
```

***The next step is to reboot the Win PC.***

***After the reboot, check the new openssh client status:***
(from ADMIN cmd or powershell)

```
PS C:\> Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

***2) Now we have the Linux server and Win PC OKs.***

Because we choosed the Linux as a SSH server and the WinPC as the client, we can´t send the files to the Win PC directly from the Linux. We need to retrieve the files from the server, so the client SSH will connect to the SSH server and ask him to copy
the files. In the practice, the effect is the same, but we must type the commands from the SSH client (the Win PC). Here is the instructions:

***Data examples:***

*SSH server username:*  **harry**  (valid user in the Linux server)

*Linux server username passwd:* **test** (harry's passwd)

*SSH server IPv4 @ddress:* **200.1.1.1**  (Linux server)

*SSH server port:* **5555**   (if you changed the default port 22)
*Linux server file to transfer:* **/mandrake/star.txt**

*Win PC download folder:* **C:\Users\Harry\Downloads>**

***On the Win PC (openssh client):***

Open a cmd and go to the download folder

```
C:\Users\Harry> cd downloads
C:\Users\Harry\Downloads>
C:\Users\Harry\Downloads> scp -P 5555 harry@200.1.1.1://mandrake/star.txt
    
Hi, I am the Linux server!!!
harry@10.1.1.1's password: test
    
star.txt                      100% 2998   304.1KB/s   00:00
    
C:\Users\Harry\Downloads>
```

***And voilá!!! SCP transfer using command line as a pro (in both Win and Linux, for free).... Be free, be open networking***........